# OpenAPI Specification Query Parameters

Tags: openapi, swagger-2.0

I have been searching for a resource talking about implementing (OAS) when using query parameters while writing OpenAPI 3.0.3 or swagger "2.0" definitions.

i haven't found any resource talking about any set of standards for query parameters, so do i just assume that anything compatible with REST is allowed?

Comment: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#query

Comment: https://spec.openapis.org/oas/latest.html#style-values